# ScrollSpy is not working properly under Firefox on my page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollspy

I'm so sorry, for I write a request for you, but I can't fix my page. I read several Howto, Stack Overflow, blog entry about ScrollSpy, but I can't fix my problem. Can anyone help me?

I know, the best way is I copy-paste the page into a code sharing site, but this problem is depending on the full environment. Sorry! I hope!
The page: http://eskuvonk.dras.hu/

I have a page with fixed overlay (header), and I want to use the main scrollbar for scroll. The problem is next:
Under Chrome, the whole page is working good, but under Firefox, the menu is crazy! Highlights good menu at first scrolls, but after jump immediately the last. Why? I checked the divs in debuggers, the padding, and others are too far for indicate the end of the page.

Please, help me! My wedding is depending on it... :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `position: absolute` set on your container div -> `<div id="streak" class="container">`. Remove it and it should work just fine.

```
#streak {
  position: absolute; /*Remove Me*/
}
```

This might break the layout of your page a little bit as is, but that is what is causing the issue in FF, so you'll have to clean that up as well.

Comment: Thank your fast, and perfect answer, Schmalzy! This cause a much smaller issue! Thx again!

Answer (score 0):

#### The final solution was:

- Removed all `position: absolute;` from any parent node of ScrollSpy inspected anchors.
- Replaced `padding-top: 300px;` to `margin-top: 300px;` on `body`.
- Added `margin-top: -300px; padding-top: 300px;` to `#streak` for fix the scrolling.

*FYI: The page contains fix positioned, 300px height menubar.*